# Snapping vertices not working

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, vertices

I have a problem with snapping vertices. So I have a character's body and I have a arm unattached to the body. I wanted to use the snapping tool and I had vertex selected and the magnet as well as auto merge. When I press g it doesn't snap to anything. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: An alternate way to achieve what you are trying to do is to use the merge tool (alt-M) and select at last. To save time, you can also use shift-r to repeat the last action so you don't have to use a menu every time.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment! I actually figured out that I can just use alt M to merge the vertices and the result was not that bad. Still thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In edit mode, *Snap onto itself* feature disables snapping to other vertices within the same object.[image]

**In 2.9**, the feature is under the Snap icon dropdown menu:

[image]

Comment: It still does not work for me, I have setup the buttons like you have. Maybe it is a lag? But I figured out that I can you alt M to merge the vertices. Thank you for trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered same problem(v2.83), somehow solved. hope it will work for you too.

1. Close Blender.
2. Launch blender, File> Open.
3. Under the blender file browser, go to settings.
4. Uncheck "Load UI".
5. Select the file you are working in which snap not working. load without its custom UI. It should work.

The "Project onto Self" option also created problems sometimes.
Also check for pivot point settings, Toggle X ray settings.

[image]

[image]